# c# open webrowser in many tab

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, tabs

how can i create tab  tab1 open samsung.com tab2 open hp.com ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace browsergotosamsung
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.samsung.com");
            webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.hp.com");
            webBrowser3.Navigate("http://www.IBM.com"); 
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void webBrowser3_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser2.Size
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebBrowser control does now support tabs, I guess. You need to add an own [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) where you create dynamic [TabPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage%28VS.80%29.aspx) and underlying WebBrowser controls by your own:

```
private void NavigateInNewTab(string url)
{
    // browser tab
    TabPage newBrowserTab = new TabPage();

    // the underlying browser
    WebBrowser newBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    newBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    newBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(newBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

    // add tab and its browser to the tab control
    newBrowserTab.Controls.Add(newBrowser);
    this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newBrowserTab);

    // navigate and focus new tab
    newBrowserTab.Select();
    newBrowser.Navigate(url);
}

void newBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    TabPage browserTab = (TabPage)browser.Parent;

    browserTab.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})", browser.DocumentTitle, e.Url);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.NavigateInNewTab("http://www.example1.com");
    this.NavigateInNewTab("http://www.example2.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[tabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx)

And make one tab control and and one tab pr browser webbrowser