# Enabling "Open In New Tab" item in WebBrowser's context menu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser

Is it possible to enable the "Open In New Tab" context menu item in a WebBrowser? Then I'll figure out how to handle it, but first I need to make it at least look enabled.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I suspect you would need to host it as an ActiveX control to even get close...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control does not support multi-tab navigation. You'll have to create your own tabs (for example, using the [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx) control) which would contain instances of WebBrowser. There are great explanations on how it could be implemented **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286746/open-link-in-new-tab-webbrowser-control)**, **[there](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/multitabwebbrowser.aspx)** and **[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532635/c-open-webrowser-in-many-tab)**.

Then, you'll need to customize the context menu of your WebBrowser by adding the *"Open In New Tab"* action. That action will trigger your own implementation of multi-tab navigation. To customize the context menu, check this article: <strike>[How to customize the WebBrowser context menu in C#](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2008/04/24/how-to-customize-the-webbrowser-context-menu-in-c/)</strike> **[WebBrowser Customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

Comment: The question is then, how to enable the "Open In New Tab" button in the context menu? Do I have to redo the whole context menu or can I just enable the "Open In New Tab" button that is already there, but disabled?

Comment: Just for the record, if you right click a link on a WebBrowser, there is a "Open In New Tab" disabled button. No idea why they put it there. Anyway here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(v=VS.85).aspx is an article on how to customize the context menu (I got there from the one in your answer).

Comment: You are right, and BTW, I found this article quite instructive: [Tabbed Browsing for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537636%28v=vs.8b5%29.aspx), about disabled "Control Shortcuts", so I was wrong about "no hidden open in new tab action in context menu".

Comment: Wait, Juan confirmed his question as answered without any response written? Was there a comment from someone whose profile has been deleted from StackOverflow?

Which is it, is there a quick fix to enable just the "Open in New Tab" link, or am I going to need to re-implement the entire context menu?